# How do I embed an Object as a @XmlValue in JAXB?

Tags: java, jaxb

I would like to represent an instance of `List<Map<String,Object>>` in XML as follows:

```
<row>
   <entry key="key1" xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">value1</entry>
   <entry key="key2" xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">value2</entry>
   <entry key="key3" />
   <entry key="keyDate" xsi:type="xs:dateTime" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">2012-08-19T13:00:59.412-04:00</entry>
</row>
```

where `key1` and `key2` are Strings, `key3` is nil, and `keyDate` is a date.

I can get *close* to this using the following implementation of `XmlAdapter`:

```
package net.parkerson.test1;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class JAXBMapAdapter extends XmlAdapter<JAXBMapAdapter.JAXBMap, Map<String, Object>>
{

    @Override
    public JAXBMap marshal(Map<String, Object> map) throws Exception
    {
        JAXBMap jaxbMap = new JAXBMap();
        for (Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet())
        {
            jaxbMap.entry.add(new JAXBMapEntry(entry));
        }
        return jaxbMap;

    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> unmarshal(JAXBMapAdapter.JAXBMap mappedObject) throws Exception
    {
        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        for (JAXBMapEntry entry : mappedObject.entry)
        {
            map.put(entry.key, entry.value);
        }
        return map;
    }

    public static class JAXBMapEntry
    {

        @XmlAttribute
        public String key;

        @XmlElement
        public Object value;

        public JAXBMapEntry()
        {
        }

        public JAXBMapEntry(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry)
        {
            key = entry.getKey();
            value = entry.getValue();
        }
    }

    public static class JAXBMap
    {
        public List<JAXBMapAdapter.JAXBMapEntry> entry = new ArrayList<JAXBMapAdapter.JAXBMapEntry>();
    }
}
```

and the following test code:

```
package net.parkerson.test1;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXB;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElements;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

import net.parkerson.test1.JAXBMapAdapter;

public class Test1
{
    @XmlRootElement
    public static class Thingy
    {
        @XmlElements(@XmlElement(name = "row"))
        @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type=Map.class, value=JAXBMapAdapter.class)
        public List<Map<String,Object>> rows;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Test1.Thingy thingy = new Test1.Thingy();

        Map<String,Object> thing1 = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        thing1.put("foo", "bar");
        thing1.put("date", new Date());

        Map<String,Object> thing2 = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        thing2.put("foo", "baz");
        thing2.put("date", new Date());

        List<Map<String,Object>> things = new ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>();
        things.add(thing1);
        things.add(thing2);

        thingy.rows = things;

        java.io.StringWriter sw = new java.io.StringWriter();
        JAXB.marshal(thingy, sw);
        System.out.print(sw.toString());
    }

}
```

which generates this:

```
<thingy>
    <row>
        <entry key="foo">
            <value xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">bar</value>
        </entry>
        <entry key="date">
            <value xsi:type="xs:dateTime" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">2012-08-19T13:20:57.484-04:00</value>
        </entry>
    </row>
    <row>
        <entry key="foo">
            <value xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">baz</value>
        </entry>
        <entry key="date">
            <value xsi:type="xs:dateTime" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">2012-08-19T13:20:57.484-04:00</value>
        </entry>
    </row>
</thingy>
```

What I really want is to ditch the nested `value` tag inside of the entry. My naive assumption was that I could replace the `@XmlElement` annotation on `value` to `@XmlValue`. However, this cause JAXB to puke all over the floor thusly:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor.get(TransducedAccessor.java:154)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ValueProperty.<init>(ValueProperty.java:66)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:95)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:145)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:479)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:498)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.<init>(ArrayElementProperty.java:97)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.<init>(ArrayElementNodeProperty.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:113)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:145)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:479)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:498)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.<init>(ArrayElementProperty.java:97)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.<init>(ArrayElementNodeProperty.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:113)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:145)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:479)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:305)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1100)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:143)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:110)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:202)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:376)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:574)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:522)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXB$Cache.<init>(JAXB.java:87)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXB.getContext(JAXB.java:114)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXB._marshal(JAXB.java:538)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXB.marshal(JAXB.java:431)
    at net.parkerson.test1.Test1.main(Test1.java:49)
```

I'm sure there's a way to do this using my `XmlAdapter`-based code, but I guess I've been staring at this too long to come up with it!

Answer (score 1):

Strange. If you change your Map type from `<String, Object>` to `<String, String>` it works as expected.

UPDATE:
It seems that if you force the JAXB to render the value with @XmlValue (or @XmlAttribute) it has no place to put its type info: `xsi:type="xs:dateTime" ...` It needs to be an @XmlElement

My suggestion is to use a `Map<String, String>` with an adapter that encodes/decodes from `String` to `Object` depending on the underlying type:

```
public class MySmartAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Object> {
    @Override
    public Object unmarshal(String s) throws Exception {
        //check if s is date and return date
        //check for other types
        return s;
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(Object o) throws Exception {
        return o != null ? o.toString() : null;
    }
}


public static class JAXBMapEntry
{

    @XmlAttribute
    public String key;

    @XmlValue
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MySmartAdapter.class)
    public Object value;

    public JAXBMapEntry()
    {
    }

    public JAXBMapEntry(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry)
    {
        key = entry.getKey();
        value = entry.getValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess I should note that the point is to marshal `Object` as the value type, so the right schema types are present based on JAXB's internal marshaling.

Comment: Yes, but then you can't specify the key as an attribute. I've updated my answer with a suggestion.

Comment: This is pretty close; I'll play around with it and see if I can get there from here. If so, you win. :D